# What's the distribution of eigenvalues of a real and symmetric Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Can you please help me find the distribution of eigenvalues of a Toeplitz matrix $\mathbf{K}$ that is constructed as follows:
$$\mathbf{K}=\left[
                 \begin{array}{cccc}
                   1 & \rho & \ldots & \, \, \rho^{N-1} \\
                   \rho & 1 & \ldots &  \, \,\rho^{N-2}\\
                   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                   \rho^{N-1} & \rho^{N-2} & \ldots & 1 \\
                 \end{array}
               \right].$$
where $0 \leq \rho < 1$.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Farzad

Comment: what do you mean by 'distribution' ? Are all the elements numbers (as opposed to random variables) ? Do you need this in analytical form or is a numerical solution sufficient ?

Comment: @ Andre, Thanks a lot for your comment, you are right. Then, there is any analytical equation to evaluate eigenvalues?

Comment: Because this question is purely about the eigenvalues of these matrices, it is more suited for posting on math.SE.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2815525/339790

Answer (score 4):

For large $N$, the eigenvalues of $K$ are approximately distributed as $2\pi f(\lambda)$ evaluated at frequencies $-\pi + 2\pi j/N$; $f(\lambda)$ is the spectral density associated to the covariance sequence in your Toeplitz matrix. See for instance [Hannan, E.J. Time Series Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412204800), Chap. 1 towards the end.

You may find more details in [Grenander & Szego, Toeplitz forms and their applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001Q8VY3W), but I do not have that book at hand and cannot say from memory if 
it will answer your question more precisely.

Comment: @Tusell, thanks a lot for your answer. I have some questions: 1) I think in frequency range $-\pi+2\pi j/N$ there should be $\lambda$ parameter aomewhere, 2) is $f(\lambda) = |\frac{-2\ln \rho}{(\ln \rho)^2+ (2\pi/N\lambda)}|^2$?

Comment: @Farzad: sorry I couldn't answer earlier. Was on a holiday and not connected. $\lambda$ takes values $\lambda_j = -\pi+2\pi j/N$ for integer values of $0 \le j \le N$. The spectral density is the Fourier transform of the covariance sequence, hence for your case would be something like $\frac{1}{2\pi}(1 + \sum_{j}\rho^{|j|}\cos(\lambda_j))$.

Comment: @Farzad The range $\lambda_j = -\pi + 2\pi j /N$ for $0\leq j \leq N$ doesn't seem right. With that range, I end up with N + 1 values, but the matrix $\mathbf{K}$ will have only ${N}$ eigenvalues. I think it should be $0 \leq j < N$.